# Spark: way to join each row of dataframe with all rows of another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Assuming I am having the following dataframes:

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq("a1" -> "a2", "b1" -> "b2", "c1" -> "c2")).toDF("a", "b")
val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq("aa1" -> "aa2", "bb1" -> "bb2")).toDF("aa", "bb")
```

And I want the following:

```
 | a  | b  | aa  | bb  |
 ----------------------
 | a1 | a2 | aa1 | aa2 |
 | a1 | a2 | bb1 | bb2 |
 | b1 | b2 | aa1 | aa2 |
 | b1 | b2 | bb1 | bb2 |
 | c1 | c2 | aa1 | aa2 |
 | c1 | c2 | bb1 | bb2 |
```

So each row of `df1` to map to all of the rows of `df2`. The way I am doing it is the following:

```
val df1_dummy = df1.withColumn("dummy_df1", lit("dummy"))
val df2_dummy = df2.withColumn("dummy_df2", lit("dummy"))
val desired_result = df1_dummy
                       .join(df2_dummy, $"dummy_df1" === $"dummy_df2", "left")
                       .drop("dummy_df1")
                       .drop("dummy_df2")
```

It gives the desired results but it seems a bit of a bad way. Is there a more efficient way of doing that? any recommendation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what `crossJoin` is for:

```
val result = df1.crossJoin(df2)

result.show()
// +---+---+---+---+
// |a  |b  |aa |bb |
// +---+---+---+---+
// |a1 |a2 |aa1|aa2|
// |a1 |a2 |bb1|bb2|
// |b1 |b2 |aa1|aa2|
// |b1 |b2 |bb1|bb2|
// |c1 |c2 |aa1|aa2|
// |c1 |c2 |bb1|bb2|
// +---+---+---+---+
```