# Most suitable type of join when trying to combine each row of a dataframe with some rows of another dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have the following situation which I've solved in a very inefficient way:

I have a dataframe called `dfUniques` where each row contains a different value from the others (e.g.: 1K rows, but it could be much more, or even less than 100 rows). And a dataframe called `dfFull`, where it can be found in some of its rows the same values that are present in `dfUniques`. The `dfFull` is much bigger than `dfUniques`, and also it has 3 times the number of columns than `dfUniques`. What I want to do is to find all rows in `dfFull` where the columns in common with `dfUniques` have the same values that a row in it. Because the objective is count how many rows from the `dfUniques` are in `dfFull`.

The way I've implemented is wrong (I think) because it takes a lot of time, and also I'm using the `collect()` call (and I know it is not the best when data become big). This is my code:

```
dfUniques.collect().foreach{
  row => {
   val singlerowRDD = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(row)), myschema)
   val matching = dfFull
      .join(singlerow, columnsInCommon)
      .select(selColumns.head, selColumns.tail: _*)
   val matchingCount = matching.count()
   println("instances that matched\t" + matchingCount)

   if (matchingRBCount > 0){
        val dfAggr = matching.groupBy("name").avg(selColumns: _*)
        resultData = resultData.union(dfAggr)
  }
}
```

}

I think a good approach should be using some `join`, but I cannot find which is the best to do what I want. Any suggestion?
I've found this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51679966/5081366) but it is not for my case, because the post try to join each row of a dataframe with all rows of another dataframe, but I want to obtain just the rows that match with each row of `dfUniques`. Well, I hope to be clear.

Comment: why are you not doing a join on the original two dataframes? Also, your code is weird, when you really would just check for a single value `v` in a dataframe, why not use a `filter(col = val)` then? But still, why not doing a join on the two original dataframes - and if you know one is small, do a **broadcast join**

Comment: Yes, you were right about the `join`, and also I know my code was weird, because of that I wanted to find a better solution.  In that moment, I couldn't realized such a simple one like Raghu showed me: `left semi`. Just to clarify, I didn't want to check a single value `v`, what I wanted to check was a single `row` (multiple columns at once), Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, join is the best way to go. In your case ,'left semi' will be applicable. You can also read various types of spark joins from here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

```
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2),(1,3),(9,9),(2,4),(2,10),(3,5),(10,9),(3,6),(3,8),(7,9),(4,5),(19,1),(20,4),(22,3),(30,5),(67,4)],schema=['a','b'])
tst1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2),(2,5),(7,6)],schema=['a','c'])
tst_res= tst.join(tst1,on='a',how='left_semi')

tst_res.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  2|  4|
|  2| 10|
|  7|  9|
+---+---+
```